# What is the equivalent for $app->pass() from Slim V2 in Slim V3?

Tags: php, slim

I'm migrating a system from Slim V2 to Slim V3...

In v2 project i have something like:

```
$app->get('/:text', function($text) use ($app) {
   if(!existsOnDb($text)) {
       $app->pass();
   }

   $app->render("mytemplate.html", ...) //Render db content of text
});

$app->get('/hola', ....); 
$app->get('/route2', ....);
$app->get('/route3', ....);
```

So, if i call `GET /hola` and "hola" exists on database, it renders `mytemplate.html`
But if `hola` does not exists, it instruct the router to "pass" and try to find another route that match (In my example, entering and executing the second defined route)

Is there something similar in Slim V3?

Comment: In Slim 3 its possible to redirect to a named route then.

Comment: I don't want a redirect... I want to process the same request with another defined route (like in slim v2). Because if i did a redirect, i think it will enter into a loop. As you can see, the routes could share the same "pattern"

Comment: And why the downvote?

Comment: I think Slim v3 does't support `pass` anymore, because it has Middlewares now. Another option would be to create a very generic route with a placeholder and rendering the template depending on the given routing arguments.

Comment: Yes, thats what im doing right now.. ;). Just curious why `pass` is not available in V3